# Link to Youtube video via middleman website - SEO perspective

Tags: seo, wordpress, links, youtube

It would be great to hear some opinions on my issue. I have WordPress website and YouTube channel. I would like to put links to my YouTube videos on some other websites. I am wondering if it is good (bad?) idea to share links that points to page on my website, and then through WordPress plugin the website seamlessly redirects user to YouTube video.

So basically is it better (from SEO perspective) to share this kind of link:  `http://example.com/dogs-video` (301 redirect to YouTube) or `http://youtube.com/dogs-video`?

I was thinking that sharing videos through links pointing to my website would result in more external services pointing to my site and finally higher Google Search position.

Any help is very appreciated. Cheers, Luke

Comment: Which site are you trying to optimize the SEO for?  Your web site or your You Tube channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't help you as Google follows redirects and the site that the link ultimately redirects to ultimately point to gets credit for the link. So, no, this isn't  helpful or worthwhile to do for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JohnConde said, Google isn't going to credit your website if the ultimate 301 is pointing to YouTube.

If you want the biggest bang for your buck, why don't you embed the YouTube hosted videos on your site? You could create a playlist with each video first as well as some other videos secondarily, but either way the user has the option to view the video on your site.

You could add rich data markup for video object, furthering your SEO, as well as gaining additional links to your page. Additionally, you can add YouTube annotations to your video channel or other videos/playlists.

If all else fails, users know they have the option to visit your YouTube page from that video. That's what I would do for the maximum SEO bang.